# searching in LDAP via PHP

Tags: php, ldap, php-7

I am following this script

http://php.net/manual/en/ldap.examples-basic.php

and I can't understand this line of code due to lack of knowledge of LDAP

```
$sr=ldap_search($ds, "o=My Company, c=US", "sn=S*");
```

what extacly is o and c?

for sn, I am assuming and based on the comments from the code it's a surname entry.

EDIT :

anyway, what should I ask the admin about the PHP configuration, for example I want to query a list of users or authenticate a user to my php script, what are the values I need to acquire from the admin. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

o is short for organization and c is short for country.

Next time try google before asking it here. The answer was the first hit on a simple google search.

Try looking here for more information:
[Ldap Tutorial](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/perl/excerpts/system-admin-with-perl/ten-minute-ldap-utorial.html)

Comment: any value I'll assign here will work or it should be from the LDAP admin. I apologize. last question, what questions and configuration values should I ask the LDAP admin. thanks!

Comment: That totally depends on the structure of your LDAP. At my work it is OU=Kantoor,DC=[Company Name],DC=local to connect to the LDAP. And  OU=Users,OU=Kantoor,DC=[Company name],DC=local to go into the right  Organisatie unit. And for searching for users sAMAccountName={0}  ( this is mostly cn={0})

Comment: anyway, what should I ask the admin about the PHP configuration, for example I want to query a list of users or authenticate a user to my php script, what are the values I need to acquire from the admin. thanks.

Comment: Try this? [http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-get-entries.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-get-entries.php)